# Dirac's theorem proof using induction

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose we have to sit $2n$ kids around a round table where each kid has more friends than enemies and any pair of kids will mutually be friends or enemies. How can they be seated together such that no kid has an enemy as a neighbour?

This happens to be [Dirac's theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirac%27s_Theorem). I am looking for a proof that does not use concepts from graph theory. I am strictly looking for an induction-based proof.

Here's my attempt.

For $n=1$, this is easy since both kids will (necessarily) be friends. Let's assume the proposition holds for $n$.

When $n \to n+1$, note that each kid has $\geq n$ friends. If we pick any $2n$ kids arbitrarily, each kid will still have more friends than enemies. Make them seated in a way such that everyone has a friendly neighbour. This is possible due to our hypothesis. Now there will be a total of $2n$ pairs of neighbours and we have two more kids who aren't given a seat yet.

Can we proceed from here?

Comment: You are talking about graph theory the whole time; you cannot *avoid* using concepts from graph theory. What you can do is take any existing proof, rephrase it in terms of kids, friends, and seats, and pretend no graph theory is happening.

Comment: Also, "each kid will still have more friends than enemies" in the induction step is false; one of the kids might have had only $n+1$ friends and $n$ enemies, and end up at $n-1$ friends and $n$ enemies once you pick $2n$ of the $2n+2$ kids.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for the correction. Also, you're right I guess: I'll just rephrase it and pretend there's no graph theory involved. Win-win.

Comment: A is friends with B, B with C, C with D, D with A. Now you say you can pick arbitrarily two of them and seat them. But if you'd pick A and C,  you wouldn't be able to seat them. Therefore it doesn't seem to me  that induction is a logical way to proof this